# Unity XCode iOS crash on launch

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, crash

I am working on the Unity iOS game. It was working fine then suddenly when I appended through unity and try to run through XCode following exception occurred. It is happening even with my backup XCode project as well. After that I created a test project still gives the same error.

> dyld: Symbol not found: __Unwind_SjLjUnregister   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled GameCenter for the project?  In Xcode, select your target on the left, then click the Capabilities tab.  Switch **Game Center** to **On**.  This will link the GameKit framework.